# Python (minimal) great-circle distance between sets of points

Tags: python, arrays, performance, distance, spherical-coordinate

Is there a Python package for efficiently computing the minimal great-circle distance for each (latitude, longitude) point in array `a` to each (latitude, longitude) point in array `b`? For example [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) unfortunately does not support spherical distances as far as I can see.

With many data points (e.g. `a` and `b` have ~70000 and ~1200 points, respectively), manual calculation similar to the example below becomes too slow, if repeated iterations with different `a` and `b` arrays are required.

```
deg2rad = np.pi/180.0
rho_cos = (np.sin(lat1[:,None]*deg2rad)*np.sin(lat2[None,:]*deg2rad) +
      np.cos(lat1[:,None]*deg2rad)*np.cos(lat2[None,:]*deg2rad)*np.cos(np.abs(lon1[:,None] - lon2[None,:])*deg2rad))    
rho = np.arccos(rho_cos) / deg2rad
rho_min = np.nanmin(rho,axis=1)
```

Comment: you could save some multiplications by avoiding the repeated multiplication /division by deg2rad, but the bulk of the work seems to be the cos and arccos of 84 million values - this is going to take some time no matter what you do...

Comment: on second thoughts,you could also take the maximum of rho_cos first and the arccos of this number should be equivalent to the minimum of arccos(rho_cos). This could save you a bunch of computations.

Comment: @pygri: thanks for the comments! As you said `deg2rad` can be pre-multiplied to the one-dimensional `lat` and `lon` arrays, the `abs` is not needed because `cos` is an even function, and taking the maximum of the `cos` values may also help. But unfortunately I suspect huge time gains are not to be expected overall.

Comment: another thing is, what about converting the lon and lat to x,y,z coordinates and applying the cdist function from scipy mentioned? you could compare how fast that is. My intuition would be that minimal great circle distance is equivalent to minimal cartesian distance in 3D...

Comment: @pygri: probably your intuition is correct, I tried just a `cdist` with random arrays of size 75000 and 1500 and it takes ~1.5 sec, compared to ~4 sec for the full great-circle computation, so this already means a factor of three or so...

Comment: then I'll write that up as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that a great circle length is proportional to the length of its chord, the minimal great circle distance is equivalent to the minimal distance of the points embedded in euclidean 3D space.

So I would suggest to compute the x,y,z coordinates equivalent to each latitude and longitude pair, and use the mentioned scipy function

```py
scipy.spatial.distance.cdist
```

to find the minimal 3D euclidian distance, which can be easily converted back to great circle distance.